Run minifi-0.5.0 on the jdk17 base image
we are using openjdk:8-jre in Dockerfile as base image to build the minifi containerized image to run our minifi application.
Here's how my Dockerfile looks like :-
FROM openjdk:8-jre
MAINTAINER Apache MiNiFi <dev@nifi.apache.org>

ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ARG MINIFI_VERSION=0.5.0

ENV MINIFI_BASE_DIR /opt/minifi
ENV MINIFI_HOME $MINIFI_BASE_DIR/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION
ENV MINIFI_BINARY_URL https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/minifi/$MINIFI_VERSION/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz

# Setup MiNiFi user
RUN groupadd -g $GID minifi || groupmod -n minifi `getent group $GID | cut -d: -f1`
RUN useradd --shell /bin/bash -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -m minifi

RUN mkdir -p $MINIFI_HOME

ADD sh/ ${MINIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/
RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la ${MINIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/; chmod +x ${MINIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/start.sh; ls -la ${MINIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/'

# Download, validate, and expand Apache MiNiFi binary.
RUN curl -fSL $MINIFI_BINARY_URL -o $MINIFI_BASE_DIR/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    && echo "$(curl $MINIFI_BINARY_URL.sha256) *$MINIFI_BASE_DIR/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xvzf $MINIFI_BASE_DIR/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz -C $MINIFI_BASE_DIR \
    && rm $MINIFI_BASE_DIR/minifi-$MINIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz

RUN chown -R minifi:minifi $MINIFI_HOME
USER minifi

# Startup MiNiFi
CMD ${MINIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/start.sh

Since 8-jre has vulnerabilities, we are trying to change the jdk base image to openjdk:17-jdk (So instead of FROM openjdk:8-jre using openjdk:17-jdk) but while running the container getting following java error ...
MiNiFi running with PID 8.
tail: cannot open '/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/logs/minifi-app.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Bootstrap Classpath: /opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/conf:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/lib/bootstrap/*:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/lib/*
Java home: /usr/java/openjdk-17
MiNiFi home: /opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/conf/bootstrap.conf

2024-06-27 12:01:32,735 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache MiNiFi...
2024-06-27 12:01:32,738 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: /opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0
2024-06-27 12:01:32,741 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.Command Command: /usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java -classpath /opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./conf:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-expression-language-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-properties-loader-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-jsp-jdt-2.3.3.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/guava-18.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/apache-jsp-8.0.33.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-registry-client-0.2.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-write-ahead-log-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-client-dto-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-registry-flow-diff-0.2.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-properties-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-util-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-http-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-server-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/minifi-runtime-0.5.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-security-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-continuation-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-security-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-core-api-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-cluster-protocol-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/curator-framework-2.11.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-logging-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-flowfile-repo-serialization-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/quartz-2.2.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/apache-jsp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-persistent-provenance-repository-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/json-smart-2.3.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/curator-client-2.11.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-registry-data-model-0.2.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-schema-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-api-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-runtime-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-registry-security-utils-0.2.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-web-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/commons-collections4-4.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-io-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-nar-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jersey-client-2.26.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-servlets-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/minifi-framework-core-0.5.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/httpcore-nio-4.4.5.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-authorization-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-site-to-site-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/json-path-2.4.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-api-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-xml-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/minifi-nar-utils-0.5.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jetty-webapp-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-user-actions-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/commons-io-2.5.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/apache-el-8.0.33.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-security-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-authorizer-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-data-provenance-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/curator-recipes-2.11.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jersey-common-2.26.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jersey-entity-filtering-2.26.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.26.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/minifi-utils-0.5.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/jersey-hk2-2.26.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-repository-models-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-site-to-site-client-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-administration-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-socket-utils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/javax.el-3.0.1-b10.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./lib/nifi-framework-core-1.7.0.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx256m -Xms256m -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/./conf/nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=35429 -Dapp=MiNiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/logs org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.lang.ProcessImpl.pid accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6b06aa9b**
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.getPid(RunMiNiFi.java:1409)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.startMiNiFi(RunMiNiFi.java:1161)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.start(RunMiNiFi.java:1204)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.main(RunMiNiFi.java:247)
tail: '/opt/minifi/minifi-0.5.0/logs/minifi-app.log' has appeared;  following new file
2024-06-27 12:01:33,184 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi Launching MiNiFi...
2024-06-27 12:01:33,251 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 33783
2024-06-27 12:01:33,264 **ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi Failure to launch MiNiFi due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.BootstrapListener.sendCommand(BootstrapListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.BootstrapListener.start(BootstrapListener.java:86)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi.<init>(MiNiFi.java:89)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi.main(MiNiFi.java:247)
2024-06-27 12:01:33,266 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi Initiating shutdown of MiNiFi server...
2024-06-27 12:01:33,269 WARN [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.minifi.MiNiFi Problem occurred ensuring MiNiFi server was properly terminated due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...

From online resources got to know we can set we can set these two parameters for resolution but can someone please help me on this part.
<argLine>
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
</argLine>

Link to this workaround found online:- Module java.base does not "opens java.lang" (Java 17.0.4.1)
If anyone faced this error and setting up the following parameter would help, how exactly can we set this on dockerfile while building the image or in Dockerfile itself?
Also, I tried to setup jdk-17 on my local system and tried to run nifi-1.8.0 which is also giving me same error as above which was running fine with jre1.8.0

Please try not to post images of text.
